# Chrome extensions broken

Tags: google-chrome

I encountered a problem last month,that my Edit this Cookie extension didn't work on my laptop,but work well on my desktop.These two chrome login with the same account.The system are both Windows 8.1 Enterprise.Chrome version 40.0.2214.111 (64-bit).Chrome shows [This extension may be damaged].And if I click Repair,chrome will re-download the extension but failed with the same problem.There are about 30+ extensions at running mode,but only ETC and another exchange rate extension has this problem.I tried to recover my system but this problem happened again after a few days.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the Chrome user profile?  This will let download all the data again.

Comment: It worked again after I updated to 41.0.2272.89.It seems that the extension wasn't compatible with chrome 40.0.2214.111.And I also tried to delect ./chrome/user/localstate and restart the chrome.The extension could be repaired and worked again until I closed chrome and run it again.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked again after I updated to 41.0.2272.89.It seems that the extension wasn't compatible with chrome 40.0.2214.111.
And I also tried to delect ./chrome/user/localstate and restart the chrome.The extension could be repaired and worked again until I closed chrome and run it again.